# how to verify if variable exist in parent class in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have to add all the variables exist in parent class in one list in child class. However all the variables in the parent class is not mandatory.

Is there any way i can figure out if variable exist in parent class or not ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     pass
... 
>>> B.__bases__
(<class '__main__.A'>,)
>>> getattr(B.__bases__[0],'x',False)
False
```

Or more comprehensivley:

```
class A(object):
    x = 5

class B(A):
    y = 6
    x = 7

print(getattr(B.__bases__[0],'y',False))
print(getattr(B.__bases__[0],'x',False))
```

Outputs

```
False
5
>>>
```

So just check wether or not `False` is returned, if it is then you can conclude the attribute doesn't exist in the parent class.

Comment: Do we have same thing for child class. Say i want to know what if atrribute is defined in child class or not ??

Comment: @GaurangShah I imagine not easily, the parent class has no way of knowing that it's being derived from

Answer (score 0):

If you know what attributes you're looking for, you can match them against `dir(parent class)`